# Getting exception while saving a .pptx file

Tags: c#, office-interop, com-interop

I have a Presentation object as follows,

```
using Presentation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation;
Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Add(MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

after some processing, at the time of saving,

```
pptPresentation.SaveAs(@"c:\temp\myPPT.pptx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
```

it's throwing an exception.

[image]

I will greatly appreciate any help with this, it's got me stumped.

Environment Details:- Windows 2008 Server(x64), .NET 3.5, IIS7

Comment: And what is the ErrorCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the magical solution.

I just created two folders in the Windows 2008 Server

**C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop and
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop**

And after applying read permission to the folders, the ppt is getting save in the local directory of the server.
[Source](http://forums.iis.net/t/1166203.aspx?ASP%20net%20PowerPoint%20Creator%20Problem)

Comment: Yes, This steps is working for me as well. I given permission to IIS Users as well.